# One-to-one virtual IP translation

Tags: networking, iptables

I've got a bunch of WAN IPs which I want to translate to a bunch of LAN IPs, but only open some ports. None of WAN IPs I want to translate are the primary WAN IP the router uses to connect to the internet.

For example I want to translate
- WAN IP 216.58.216.238 to LAN IP 10.10.10.10 and open ports 80 and 443

Initially `ifconfig` shows the following interfaces: `br0`, `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`, `lo`, `vlan1`, `vlan2`.

`vlan2` has my external IP address assigned to it.

How would I do the translation?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 216.58.216.238 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 216.58.216.238 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:80
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10 -j SNAT --to 216.58.216.238
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I can't access my service on 10.10.10.10:80 from an external network using port 216.58.216.238:80.

running `ifconfig` after rebooting I get some extra interfaces showing up. For example: `eth0:1`. It has the same HWaddr as `eth0` and `vlan2`, and it has the correct external ip address assigned to its `inet addr`, but I still can't see the device outside my network.

if I run `iptables -t nat -vnL` it seems to have registered something. For example I have:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5212 packets, 475K bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in    out  source      destination
...
0    0     DNAT   tcp  --  eth0  *    0.0.0.0/0   216.58.216.238     tcp dpt:80 to 10.10.10.10:80
...
```

Any ideas as to what I need to change to allow access?

**edit.**

I could get my services to work using the following commands, but they allow all ports to go through. There are so many switches and options for iptables...

```
ifconfig eth0:1 216.58.216.238 netmask 255.255.255.0
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 216.58.216.238 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10 -j SNAT --to 216.58.216.238
```

Comment: Try deleting that POSTROUTING rule.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried removing it, but it still wouldn't work. Something else did work though, as described in my edit, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: have you enabled ip forwarding?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't think I need ip forwarding. I have an external IP for every computer on my LAN. Like I said, the configuration after my edit in my question works. Just not sure why it does and the old one doesn't

Comment: You need IP forwarding if your WAN IP (216.58.216.238) is on a different host to your LAN IP (10.10.10.10) - ie: if it isn't delivering it locally & has to *forward* it.